# Melanocyte count in our skin

Tags: dermatology, measurement, melanin

How many melanocytes can be found in one square milimeter of the skin. Is 1500 melanocytes per square-milimeter skin indeed the correct number?

Comment: Since this already has an accepted answer, I won't migrate it, but this is not a health related question. It would have been more suited for biology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The count of melanocytes per square mm depends on the body region and 1500 seems to be the upper limit. Interestingly [in different races, the number of melanocytes is THE SAME.](http://www.histology.leeds.ac.uk/skin/pigmentation.php)

> > Quoting from:[Understanding the Melanocyte Distribution in Human Epidermis: An Agent-Based Computational Model Approach](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0040377)
>
> The skin color in young and healthy individuals is remarkably uniform.
>   A major reason for this is that the melanocytes are evenly distributed
>   throughout the basal layer of the epidermis. The density of
>   melanocytes varies with the body site from around 900 melanocytes per
>   square mm on the back to around 1500 melanocytes per square mm in the
>   genital region.